# how to find data in array vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to find data by value, but the value is an array .. how?

```
 mylokasi [
    {
        id: 1 ,
            name : koko
    },
    {
        id: 2 ,
            name : doni
    },
    {
        id: 3 ,
            name : dika
    },
    {
        id: 4 ,
            name : ujang
    },
    ]

    mylokasi.find(p => p.id== [2,3,4,3]).name
```

I want to display all the data in the array [2,3,4,3]

result value so : doni,dika,ujang,dika

Comment: Loop the array, and grab the object property from the array index for example ``myLokasi[0].id`` would be valid, obviously many ways to achieve the desired result. a loop is just one.

Comment: can give an example?

Comment: `[2,3,4,3].map(id => mylokasi.find(e => e.id == id).name)`

also I want to mention that `qontol==penis` in indonesia language idk why this guy use it as name example

Comment: let arrr = mylokasi.map((item) => item.name) gives you new array like ['koko', 'doni', 'dika', 'qotol']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) you can achieve your goal !

Try this code it's help you !

```js
  let mylokasi = [{ id: 1, name: 'koko' }, { id: 2, name: 'doni' }, { id: 3, name: 'dika' }, { id: 4, name: 'qotol' }];
    let arr = [2, 3, 4, 3];
    let res = arr.map((id) => (mylokasi.find(x => x.id == id).name));
    console.log(res, 'res');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the filter and map functions:

```
mylocasi
  .filter(item => [2, 3, 4, 3].includes(item.id))
  .map(item => item.name)
```

Comment: @Harry Wardana, this guy beat me to it. but this is an example aswell

Comment: It's worth noting that in JavaScript indices start at 0, so `1` is actually the second item

Comment: Better off actually comparing the `id` field instead of assuming the `id` equals to `array index + 1`. By designing an `id` field probably means that the array may not necessarily be sorted and continuous.

Comment: Very good point. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks @RickyMo

Comment: But your updated answer isn't doing what OP want. Please check OP's expected output result.